# Subspaces of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The Lie correspondence is well understood. For 'nice enough' Lie groups $G$ (with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$) every sub-group $H < G$ has a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h} < \mathfrak{g}$ given by $\log(H)$.

Rather than sub algebras I want to know about vector sub spaces of $\mathfrak{g}$. Clearly these don't exponentiate to sub Lie groups of $G$ in general. But what do they exponentiate to? Is there some clear correspondence between sub spaces of $\mathfrak{g}$ and sub something of $G$ and what is this something.

Also, the converse issue. Which subsets $S \subset G$ have that $\log(S)$ is a vector subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: I guess that the exponentials of linear subspaces are just submanifolds of the Lie group, nothing more.

Comment: Surely more can be said about such sub manifolds. For example, they all contain the identity. There are in a sense more sub manifolds of $G$ than there are vector subspaces of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ so I would expect more could be said.

Comment: For example 1d subspaces of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ exponentiate to $U{1}$ subgroups and 2d subspaces to 2 sphears which are not subgroups.